# MySql Freely avaliable dataset

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb, testing

I need MySQL dataset for testing purposes to check and improve performance and optimization.

Is there any freely available dataset (MySQL) of 200k rows ??

Answer (score 0):

MySQL provides an Employee Database for instruction and learning purposes:

Database on GitHub: https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db

Instructions and Information: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/

Answer (score 0):

9M "geonames":  http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/

Be sure to think through what types of queries you need to hit it with.  And whether you will be "Normalizing".  Etc.